# Create Array based on Formula applied to Source Array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to apply four formulas to a set of coordinates I have in an array, to generate two additional arrays that I can then plot.

The two new arrays called 'internal_edge' and 'external_edge'.

In the code below, I have printed the four equations I need to apply to the X and Y of both 'internal_edge' and 'external_edge'.

```py
import numpy as np
import math as m
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

track_width = 0.25

centre_line = np.array([
    [5.2838386568469105, 0.5533114231405133],[5.366471208948866, 0.5138588293370626],[5.449968630730311, 0.47627584038467463],[5.534812288152224, 0.4418872118882958],[5.621950766713397, 0.4139674411266211],[5.711536576482786, 0.3955402988007556],[5.80273779150609, 0.38945006681201744],[5.893859166442468, 0.3968403768909704],[5.983006824666859, 0.41711137467093196],
])

x1, y1 = centre_line.T
#Internal X[0] Value:
print(track_width*m.cos(m.radians(m.degrees(m.atan2(y1[1]-y1[0],x1[1]-x1[0]))+90))+x1[1])
#Internal Y[0] Value:
print(track_width*m.sin(m.radians(m.degrees(m.atan2(y1[1]-y1[0],x1[1]-x1[0]))+90))+y1[1])
#External X[0] Value:
print(track_width*m.cos(m.radians(m.degrees(m.atan2(y1[1]-y1[0],x1[1]-x1[0]))-90))+x1[1])
#External Y[0] Value:
print(track_width*m.sin(m.radians(m.degrees(m.atan2(y1[1]-y1[0],x1[1]-x1[0]))-90))+y1[1])

internal_edge = np.array([
])
external_edge = np.array([
])

x2, y2 = internal_edge.T
x3, y3 = external_edge.T

plt.scatter(x1,y1,color='blue')
plt.scatter(x2,y2,color='green')
plt.scatter(x3,y3,color='red')
plt.show()
```

I now need to work out how to apply these to every single data point in my array to generate my new arrays.

[Perfect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZfEf.png)
[Imperfect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsGxj.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Just to clarify, are you trying to work out how to apply the formulas to [`[(x1[0], y1[0]), (x1[1], y1[1])]`, `[(x1[1], y1[1]), (x1[2], y1[2])]`, `[(x1[2], y1[2]), (x1[3], y1[3])]`, ..., `[(x1[i], y1[i]), (x1[i+1], y1[i+1])]`]?

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

track_width = 0.25

centre_line = np.array([
    [5.2838386568469105, 0.5533114231405133],[5.366471208948866, 0.5138588293370626],[5.449968630730311, 0.47627584038467463],[5.534812288152224, 0.4418872118882958],[5.621950766713397, 0.4139674411266211],[5.711536576482786, 0.3955402988007556],[5.80273779150609, 0.38945006681201744],[5.893859166442468, 0.3968403768909704],[5.983006824666859, 0.41711137467093196],
])

x1, y1 = centre_line.T

# adjust for full dataset maybe?
x1 = np.append(x1, x1[0])
y1 = np.append(y1, y1[0])

angle = np.arctan2(y1[1:] - y1[:-1], x1[1:] - x1[:-1])


internal_edge = np.array([
    track_width*np.cos(angle + np.deg2rad(90)) + x1[1:],
    track_width*np.sin(angle + np.deg2rad(90)) + y1[1:],
])

external_edge = np.array([
    track_width*np.cos(angle - np.deg2rad(90)) + x1[1:],
    track_width*np.sin(angle - np.deg2rad(90)) + y1[1:],
])

x2, y2 = internal_edge
x3, y3 = external_edge

plt.scatter(x1,y1,color='blue')
plt.scatter(x2,y2,color='green')
plt.scatter(x3,y3,color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks great. Running this with the full dataset is not quite perfect however. I've attached two images to the original post, one of how it should look (generated when I was testing by manually inputting the desired arrays), and the one generated by your code. Would you be able to take a look and let me know what you think? This is frying my brain at this point!

Comment: how about now? don't have the dataset to test on

Comment: That solves the missing datapoint problem, but we still have those two wrong values in the top left.

Comment: angle[121] == 0 which coincides with weird anomaly on the graph. Idk how 2 fix it something math related

Comment: There was a duplicate datapoint that was causing it. I've removed the duplicate (121) and now works fine!